# Where to obtain qmake (QT) compiler for netbeans?

Tags: qt, netbeans

I would like to use netbeans 8 for make QT applications. How ever, I have to specify the qmake file, which is for compiling QT apps. Is there any official source where I can get it? I tried google a lot, but haven't found any normal place. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qmake is a program that compiles Project Files (.pro) into a Makefile. Think of it as "autoconf" of Qt world. To compile a Qt project, you only need to perform 2 steps,

- run `qmake` to generate a Makefile from the Project File (.pro)
- run `make` to build your application

netbeans.org has a step-by-step guide how do set things up,

https://netbeans.org/kb/72/cnd/qt-applications.html

Comment: Isn't the question about where to get `qmake`from?

Comment: qmake is *part of* Qt distribution.

Comment: Which is exactly the answer. Which is why I wrote exactly that in my answer ;-)

Comment: thanks. your answer seems to be correct. Although unfortunately there's a url there in the manual linking to nokia.com, which has been down for a while.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/ for Qt. Maybe the maintainer of that page should be poked to update their links.

Answer (score 0):

qmake is a Qt specific replacement for the make utility, not a compiler. It is part of the Qt distribution actually... Just checked here, yes, it is part of the libqt4-devel package. Note that obviously you need the Qt *development* packages in addition to the runtime Qt packages.

Comment: It is *not* a replacement for the make utility. Like cmake, qmake is just a makefile generator.

Comment: @KubaOber You are right, I put things to simple. It is a replacement for manually creating makefiles, not for the `make` utility itself ;-)