# What default make tool does NetBeans use

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

Iv been writing a small c program with **NetBeans 8**  on Linux. It uses this **configuration.xml** file to compile the Makefile together. I'v searched a little but there is little information on what tool supports this file or if it is a NetBeans internal tool. How could i call it from the command line etc.

i was hoping it is some alternative build tool, but so far its no scons, waf, ninja, cmake, qmake

Does anyone have experience with it?

How it looks like:

`<configurationDescriptor version="95">
  <logicalFolder name="root" displayName="root" projectFiles="true" kind="ROOT">
   <logicalFolder name="HeaderFiles" ...>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608569/can-cmake-and-netbeans-play-nice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765476/where-to-obtain-qmake-qt-compiler-for-netbeans

Comment: As for other than cmake/qmake build tools - you always can call them from your makefile, provided that your project type is `C/C++ Project with Existing Sources`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What default make tool does NetBeans use

It uses `make` per default. Default C/C++ project types generate Makefiles for you. You can use custom Makefiles instead too - and even other build tools (like CMake, QMake, ...).

> I'v searched a little but there is little information on what tool supports this file or if it is a NetBeans internal tool.

The *configurations.xml* is NetBeans internal only.

Btw. modify this file only, if you are sure what you are doing - it has the capability to break your project!

> How could i call it from the command line etc.

You mean the configurations.xml? If so; you can't. As said above, it's for NB internal usage only. However it's not necessary though. Netbeans will provide you all Makefiles you need. Those can be build using `make` the usual way.

> Does anyone have experience with it?

If the generated Makefiles don't serve your purpose you can either customize it (check comments within the files) - or write a custom one and create a project from it.

As commented by *Hekto*, [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) is an alternative build tool that [works great with NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608569/can-cmake-and-netbeans-play-nice). It's also widely used for C/C++ project and has lot's of benefits. Furthermore CMake-based projects can be used by other IDE's (like Eclipse or VisualStudio) easily - and if all fails just call it from terminal ;-).